# Python: Get 6 random numbers with minimum difference

Tags: python, random, numbers, difference

I'm trying to get 6 random generated numbers between 1 and 3600. But I want that the the individual numbers to have a minimum difference of at least 150. I already have created a function. I do receive my 6 random numbers but not the difference i expected. Where is my mistake? I can't figure it out.

I'm very new to python. I tried different methods but I'm not able to find the solution for my problem.

```
def get_random_seconds_with_difference(min_tx, max_tx, number_tx):
    s_times = []
    i_number = 0
    new_times_s = random.randint(min_tx,max_tx)
    s_times.append(new_times_s)
    while i_number < number_tx:
        new_times_s = random.randint(min_tx,max_tx)
        if new_times_s >= s_times[i_number]:
            difference_time_s = new_times_s - s_times[i_number]
        else:
           difference_time_s = s_times[i_number] - new_times_s

        if difference_time_s >= 150:
            s_times.append(new_times_s)
            i_number += 1

    return s_times
```

Comment: You don't need all those semicolons.

Comment: You can use "random.choice(range(1,3600,150))"

Comment: Thank you! Another way for the future. :)

Comment: @PasiB i don't understand what is a need for this mess code why not with simple approach..i have written simple form you can have a look if i am understanding correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it, using the same principle of rejecting invalid times until we get all the ones we need:

```
import random

def get_random_seconds_with_difference(min_tx, max_tx, number_tx):
    times = []
    while len(times) < number_tx:
        new_time = random.randint(min_tx, max_tx)
        if all(abs(new_time - time) >= 150 for time in times):
            times.append(new_time)
    return times

get_random_seconds_with_difference(0, 3600, 6)
# [2730, 435, 2069, 3264, 3496, 1091]
```

Using [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) makes the rejection logic a bit simpler, and using the `abs` of the difference lets us avoid treating two different cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're only comparing the new number with the last number in the list. You need it to check it against *all* of the number in the list to get the result you want. Below is this, using a for loop:

```
import random

def get_random_seconds_with_difference(min_tx, max_tx, number_tx):
    s_times = []
    i_number = 0
    new_times_s = random.randint(min_tx,max_tx)
    s_times.append(new_times_s)
    while i_number < number_tx:
        new_times_s = random.randint(min_tx,max_tx)
        for i in range(len(s_times)):
            if new_times_s >= s_times[i]:
                difference_time_s = new_times_s - s_times[i]
            else:
                difference_time_s = s_times[i] - new_times_s

            if difference_time_s >= 150:
                s_times.append(new_times_s)
                i_number += 1
                break

    return s_times;

print(get_random_seconds_with_difference(1, 3600, 10))
```

Note: There's probably a faster way to do this, and maybe already-built in function (see comment above with the suggestion of random.choice).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
import random
def choice(a):
    for _ in range(a):
        print(random.choice(range(1,3600,150)))

choice(6) #you can pass nomber to get value
```

**Output:-**

```
3451
2401
1201
301
1951
3451
```